# Find and update property of nested object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have somewhere in theObject a property `component` and if this has the value `"get-all"`, i want to add a property to this specific object.

```
async function getObject(theObject) {
  var result = null;
  if (theObject instanceof Array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
      result = await getObject(theObject[i]);
      if (result) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    for (var prop in theObject) {
      if (prop == 'component') {
        if (theObject[prop] == "get-all") {

          theObject.stories = [ "some example stories"];
          return theObject
        }
      }
      if (theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array) {
        result = await getObject(theObject[prop]);
        if (result) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Example Input

```
{
  "story": {
    "name": "Services",
    "content": {
      "_uid": "2b1dd39a-c9f1-4bf5-a90a-1129465edb2d",
      "body": [
        {
          "_uid": "85892460-cd4b-4bc9-8369-097b50b0839f",
          "color": {
            "_uid": "eefaa43d-7f9b-459d-b42d-fc16436dc085",
            "color": "",
            "plugin": "native-color-picker"
          },
          "style": "padding-top: 40px;\ntext-align: center;",
          "alignment": "center",
          "component": "h2",
        },
        {
          "_uid": "e3ef3c5f-391c-4be0-8b22-4f96d3dd542e",
          "slug": "technology",
          "component": "get-all",
        }
      ],
      "component": "page",
    },
    "slug": "services",
  }
}
```

Excpeteced Output

```
{
  "story": {
    "name": "Services",
    "content": {
      "_uid": "2b1dd39a-c9f1-4bf5-a90a-1129465edb2d",
      "body": [
        {
          "_uid": "85892460-cd4b-4bc9-8369-097b50b0839f",
          "color": {
            "_uid": "eefaa43d-7f9b-459d-b42d-fc16436dc085",
            "color": "",
            "plugin": "native-color-picker"
          },
          "style": "padding-top: 40px;\ntext-align: center;",
          "alignment": "center",
          "component": "h2",
        },
        {
          "_uid": "e3ef3c5f-391c-4be0-8b22-4f96d3dd542e",
          "slug": "technology",
          "component": "get-all",
          "stories": [...some example stories]
        }
      ],
      "component": "page",
    },
    "slug": "services",
  }
}
```

Comment: A single sentence is rarely enough to properly explain a problem, please try to give as much detail as you can in your description as well as including the code. (Specifically, what is wrong with the code you already have? Are there any error messages?)

Comment: for me it sounds like the function is working as expected, but there is no point of async await usage. maybe it will work as you want if you just erase all the `async` and `await` from your code

Comment: could you provide a piece of code of how you want your function to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to async/await in your recursive function, also use Object.keys and  forEach to loop through the objects something like this code

```js
const getObject = (data) => {
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    if (data[key] instanceof Object ) {
      return  getObject(data[key]);
    }
    if(key === 'component' && data[key] === 'get-all'){
      data['stories'] = ['some example stories']
    }
  });
  return  data;
};

 
console.log(getObject(data))
```